# How can i calculate a ratio when the #DIV/0! error is present

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am trying to get a formula to compute when `0` is present, and the `#DIV/0!` error is being problematic.

I want cell `H4` to calculate a ratio using cells `F4` and `G4`. This works fine when `0` is not present in cell `G4` however when `0` is present I get the `#DIV/0!` error.

How can this formula be modified so it still works out the ratio even if there is a `0` in cell `G4`?

The current formula is : `=IF(COUNT(G4)=1,SUM(F4/G4),"")`

Comment: For example, if there is a ```6``` in cell ```F4``` and ```G4``` has a ```0```, I want it to work out the ratio 6:0.

Comment: 6/0 is undefined though. Also the `SUM` in your current formula is redundant: the `SUM` of `F4/G4` is just `F4/G4`. I'm guessing you want `=F4/IF(G4=0,1,G4)`.

Comment: @BigBen that appears to work, is there any way you could look at another question I have posted? it is regarding VBA that is proving difficult if not then thanks for your help this time around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the AGGREGATE formula. By wrapping it around your formulae you can tell AGGREGATE to ignore errors. Here I have used the sum feature so it returns the same answer. The 6 flag tells it to ignore errors:

```
  =AGGREGATE(9,6,IF(COUNT(G4)=1,F4/G4,""))
```